# Зачем указатель, если есть ссылка?

Tags: c++, указатели

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void display_ptr(int *ptrint) {
    cout << *ptrint << endl;
}

void display_addr(int &toint) {
    cout << toint << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int i{ 10 };
    display_ptr(&i);
    display_addr(i);
}
```

В данном примере для меня непонятны возможности конструкции с указателем, по сравнению с передачей значения по ссылке.

Как видно, чтобы использовать значение по указателю, нужно достать его с помощью `*`, а еще передать в аргумент с помощью `&`.

Используя передачу по ссылке, ничего не нужно кроме указания в самом параметре, при этом значение также не копируется и его также можно изменять по ссылке.

Не совсем понимаю какой профит у указателей, если намного удобней передавать значение по ссылке.

Comment: ну передайте С - строку без указателя в функцию... Первичны то как раз указатели, ссылки появились позже.

Comment: На вскидку: Раз, в C++ нет нулевых ссылок. Два, нельзя создать контейнер ссылок. Три, нельзя определить оператор копирующего присваиавния для класса у которого есть поле-ссылка. Четыре, ссылку нельзя перенацелить.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Если с инглишем хорошо, то милости просим на [англоязычный стэковерфлов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in). Если в двух словах:

1. Ссылку нельзя перенацелить
2. Нельзя создать ссылку на ссылку
3. Указатель можно обнулить
4. Указатели поддерживают адресную арифметику(+, -, ++, --)
5. Указатель нужно разыменовывать
6. Указатель является переменной, которая содержит адрес памяти. Вне зависимости от того, как реализуется ссылка, ссылка имеет тот же адрес памяти что и элемент на который она ссылается.
7. Ссылки нельзя поместить в массив
8. Можно создавать константные ссылки на временные объекты

Comment: "Если с инглишем хорошо, то милости просим на англоязычный стэковерфлов." - это так можно на большую часть вопросов так отвечать. Смысл-то в том, чтобы создать базу данных ответов здесь.

Answer (score 5):

Главное это то, что ссылки всегда инициализированные. То есть не бывает нулевых ссылок, а битые ссылки это UB. Язык их таковыми считает, хотя толком ничего и не делает, чтобы они оставались инициализированными. Как и всегда в крестах, полработы ложится на программиста. Все остальные свойства ссылок вытекают из свойства инициализированности.